# Malfunctioning windows

Tags: key, power-windows, skoda

Two things malfunctioned with my Skoda Octavia windows

- One window won't operate with the 'one-touch' switch, only by holding the switch
- The 'convenience' window operation from the key fob stopped working

I tried the following

- Using the other key fob
- Replacing the key fob battery
- Resetting the window options to 'factory settings' and set it up again
- Replacing the four-window switch unit in the driver's door

but nothing worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was caused by the window controller's "Force Limiter", which had disabled the normal window operation. It can be reset by

- Opening the defective window
- Closing that window
- Releasing the button
- Holding the button in the 'close' position for several seconds.

This fixed the problem and normal window operation was restored.
It is possibly the same for other VAG based cars such as VW, Audi and Seat.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up Weather Vane!  Nice to see you were able to resolve the issue and share the solution.